# Creating a handle view for umano AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set up a sliding layout where the slide view contains a list view, and I want that list view to have a pull to refresh. To get the touch behaviour to work properly I need to have the slide view ignore touches in this list view, but I want a small view at the top to handle moving the slide view around.

I am currently using this library for the sliding behaviour:
https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Below is a summary of the layout Im using. Essentially, I don't want the *slidePanel* to handle the sliding anymore, and I just want the *dragHandle* to be the only view that can shift the slide panel.

I had tried setting the *dragHandle* to be the dragView of the *slidePanel* but I wasn't getting the results I needed.

```
<UmanoSlideView>
    <BackgroundView>
    </BackgroundView>

    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/slidePanel">

       <View
           android:id="@+id/dragHandle" />

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/list_view_showing_things" />

    </LinearLayout>
</UmanoSlideView>
```

Thanks in advance for anyone willing to help me!